# How to get instance of Parent Object and Create Related Child at the same time

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Let's say we have:

```
class Parent(Model):
    pass

class Child(Model):
    parent = ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

Now on Child Creation:

```
parent = Parent.objects.get(id=id)
Child.objects.create(parent=parent)
```

Here I can see 2 things happening, getting an instance of a parent object and then creating the child object. How I can process it at a time? on child creating.
Is it fine to follow the above approach? or we can make it better.

Comment: Yes the approach is fine, you could also use `commit=False`, will you please share actual code?

Comment: I'm not using Django forms. but accepting requests thru API endpoints. and where to use commit=False?

Comment: That is used while complex saving.

Comment: if you have id of `Parent` then `Child.objects.create(parent_id=id)`

Comment: Yeah that's what I guess looking for, Are there any performance difference in between two ?